# Can you FTP into an EC2 instance if you opted out of creating a key pair when you generated it?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, ftp, key-pair

I followed [this AWS tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/launch-a-wordpress-website/) to get a Wordpress site up and running but it instructed me not to use the keypair option so now I can not follow those instructions to FTP and make simple CSS etc. changes.

Before I blow up the whole instance, am I missing an approach that can make FTP possible?

Comment: Do you have the key pair?

Answer (score 2):

If you skipped creating key pair during instance launch, you can't connect to it. The only way to connect to that instance with (S)FTP now is to put a working key on the disk:

1. Stop the instance.
2. Detach the EBS volume and attach it to the instance that you can connect to.
3. Mount the volume and put a public key in `./ssh` folder in the home directory of the user named `bitnami`.
4. Dismount the volume, detach it and attach back to the original instance.

Seem like it's easier to just recreate the instance, this time with a private key.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'll just do that. Luckily I caught this early. I'm toying with the idea of hosting WP with AWS EC2 and I just wanted to mock some of my typical workflows to see if it will work for me. FTP, for me, is a must.